# Loading a fact table in SSIS when obtaining the dimension key isn't easy

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have a fact table that needs a join to a dimension table however obtaining that relationship from the source data isn't easy. The fact table is loaded from a source table that has around a million rows, so in accordance with best practice, I'm using a previous run date to only select the source rows that have been added since the previous run. After getting the rows I wish to load I need to go through 3 other tables in order to be able to do the lookup to the dimension table. Each of the 3 tables also has around a million rows.

I've read that best practice says not to extract source data that you know won't be needed. And best practice also says to have as light-touch as possible on the source system and therefore avoid sql joins. But in my case, those two best practices become mutually exlusive. If I only extract changed rows in the itermediary tables then I'll need to do a join in the source query. If I extract all the rows from the source system then I'm extracting much more data than I need and that may cause SSIS memory/performance problems.

I'm leaning towards a join in the extraction of the source data but I've been unable to find any discussions on the merits and drawbacks of that approach. Would that be correct or incorrect? (The source tables and the DW tables are in Oracle).

Comment: I find it downright impossible to grab fact or dimension data without using joins on source systems. If those are for some reason slow, you may ask the DBA to create an index or two. Normalized data is supposed to be queried using joins. The statement "... and therefore avoid sql joins" is pure grammatically correct nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you stage the 3 source tables that you are referencing? You may not need them in the DW, but you could have them sitting in a staging database purely for this purpose. You would still need to keep these up-to-date however, but assuming you can just pull over the changes, this may not be too bad.

Comment: What would be the difference between querying a staging table and querying the source table? Would that not have the same detremental effect on the source system? Or would you recommend staging the data on Sql Server rather than Oracle?

Comment: My thinking was that you take the data off of the production environment, so you can maintain the 'light touch' on the source system. You're right though, that for the actual SSIS lookup, you'd still have the performance concern about querying the large amount of data. But when staged, you've got more options - you can join directly in SQL, or use the SSIS Lookup task...whichever works better for you. The main thing is you're not staying connected to the live source DB.

Comment: I like revelator's suggestion.  This is something I've recently had to implement in a pre-existing ETL solution.  The source data began to grow after an acquisition and the ETL solution was now spending too much time extracting data from the source system.  So we changed the ETL to stage most of what we needed on the DW system before doing the lookups.  The bottom line is that you're at the mercy of the source data model...one way or another, you will have to use those 3 big tables to complete the fact-table load.

Comment: Presumably using database replication is an acceptable way of creating the staging environment? That's not an idea that I've read being discussed but seems like a somewhat sensible idea. The downside might be that the data that becomes the source of the ETL is changing as the source changes and therefore the benefits of staging tables to provide a stable, auditable environment won't be realised.